# PostgreSQL: optimize Rarity Score calculation

Tags: postgresql, optimization, statistics

I need to populate a value called "Rarity Score" for collectible items by one query. Here is the data I currently have:

**Items table**

```
+-----+--------+-------+
| id  |  name  | score |
+-----+--------+-------+
|   1 | Item 1 | NULL  |
|   2 | Item 2 | NULL  |
| ... | ...    | NULL  |
+-----+--------+-------+
```

**Ownerships table**

```
+---------+---------+
| item_id | user_id |
+---------+---------+
|       1 |       1 |
|       2 |       1 |
|       3 |       1 |
|       1 |       2 |
|       5 |       2 |
|       4 |       1 |
|       2 |       3 |
|     ... |     ... |
+---------+---------+
```

*Each collectible item may be collected by different users as well as each user may collect any item.*

And here is how i accomplished this task.

1. Rarity Score is calculated by the following formula:

```
score = 100 - 50 * number_of_item_ownerships / average_number_of_ownerships_per_item
```

Notice that I set the average number of item's ownerships to be the 50% rarity. Let's check the example:

```
The average number of item ownerships = (5 + 10 + 15 + 20) / 4 = 12.5
+---------------------------+----------------------------+
| number of item ownerships |           rarity           |
+---------------------------+----------------------------+
|                         5 | 100 - 50 * 5 / 12.5 = 80%  |
|                        10 | 100 - 50 * 10 / 12.5 = 60% |
|                        15 | 100 - 50 * 15 / 12.5 = 40% |
|                        20 | 100 - 50 * 20 / 12.5 = 20% |
+---------------------------+----------------------------+
```

2. The query:

```sql
UPDATE items SET score = scores.bounded_score FROM (
  WITH appearances AS (
    SELECT item_id, COUNT(*) AS number FROM ownerships GROUP BY item_id
  ),
  average AS (
    SELECT AVG(appearances.number) AS number FROM appearances
  )
  SELECT
    appearances.item_id AS item_id,
    width_bucket(100.0 - 50.0 * appearances.number / average.number, 1, 99, 98) + 1 AS bounded_score
  FROM appearances, average
) AS scores WHERE items.id = scores.item_id;
```

Some notes:

1. I'm using CTE to calculate number of item ownerships and the average value.
2. `width_bucket` keeps the score bounded between 1 and 100.

This query works fine but I have feeling that it can be greatly optimized with [Aggregate Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html). Unfortunately I'm not so expert in PostgreSQL (and math in general) so I'd like to ask for help with the optimization.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you do seems perfectly reasonable to me.

Comment: can you show real data, ddl/dml and the desired output?